# MYSQL, a column for each datatype: is it to much or is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, types

I have a function that is suppose to store variables based on their datatype, and this is table I have come up with to store those variables into. I guess what I am asking is is it smarter to have everything broken down like this or would be wiser to only have colunms for the largest for the largest datatype of a group? I.E. For string datatypes only have a `MEDIUMTEXT`. I am expecting this table to become quite large and I would like to keep the tables storage space demands as small as possible.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS form_part_detail(
form_part_detail_id  INT NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
form_part_detail_type_id   INT NOT NULL,
label   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`dt_string`    VARCHAR(255)  NULL,
`dt_text`   TEXT   NULL,
`dt_mediumtext`    MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
`dt_integer`   INT NULL,
`dt_boolean`   TINYINT(1)  NULL,
`dt_float` FLOAT NULL,
`dt_double`    DOUBLE NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (form_part) REFERENCES `form_part` (form_part_id)
FOREIGN KEY (form_part_detail_type_id) REFERENCES `form_part_detail_type` (form_part_detail_type_id)
);
```

Comment: Don't name columns after mySQL reserved words - it's begging for trouble at some point.

Comment: I fixed it so my columns are no longer using reserved words. Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I wonder whether the data type distinction is necessary at all, seeing as you're hardly likely to do anything with this data that is going to need it? (Like sums, comparisons, ordering....) I think throwing everything except memos into one `VARCHAR` column might be a valid option.

Comment: How about a separate table for each data type? That way you use only as much storage as you've got data (plus a bit of table overhead), and don't waste  6 out of 7 fields worth of space on each record.

Comment: @ Pekka - While I am not going to do with in the way sums, I will be doing a lot of comparisons. Also, I am already validating the information against a specific datatype so I might as well store it as such.

Comment: @Marc B - Having a table for each datatype would probably be the best use of storage, but the queries would be a nightmare.

Comment: @Brook true enough. but so would a single table `IF (table.fieldtype == 'string', stringfield, IF(table.fieldtype='integer', intfield, IF(.etc......)`

Comment: @Marc B - At the moment, I am using a switch combined with a few validation functions to build the query. While it requires only one INSERT query each datatype has its own value clause so it does get a little bloated. Though I guess it wouldn't be all that different to pair a datatype with its own INSERT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I found in the E-Commerce application "Magento". They dump every data type into attribute tables (attribute_type_text, attribute_type_int) to keep these dynamic and not waste the space, then join the existing using a relation between the main data object and the attributes in question.